# How to test for multiple instances of strings that match the same regex on a page with Capybara / Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, cucumber, capybara

Trying to test a page that has 3 house prices on it. Each house price could be anything as low as $10,000 and as high as $1,000,000, so I wrote a regex to try to catch any possible iterations of the numbers:

```
\$[\d]{0,1},{0,1}[\d]{2,3},{0,1}[\d]{0,3}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to correctly form the Capybara expression to verify that there are 3 iterations. The first attempt here:

```
Then(/^I should see (\d+) listings which contain the price in the correct format$/) do |times|
 expect(@page.price).to have_text("\$[\d]{0,1},{0,1}[\d]{2,3},{0,1}[\d]{0,3}", :count => times)
end
```

... gives this error:

```
Then I should see 3 listings which contain the price in the correct format
# features/step_definitions/feature_format.rb:6
Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : ["$[d]{0,1},{0,1}[d]{2,3},{0,1}[d]{0,3}"]
Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : ["$[d]{0,1},{0,1}[d]{2,3},{0,1}[d]{0,3}"]
Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : ["$[d]{0,1},{0,1}[d]{2,3},{0,1}[d]{0,3}"]
```

The second attempt here:

```
Then(/^I should see (\d+) listings which contain the price in the correct format$/) do |times|
 for i in 1..times.to_i do
  expect(@page.price).to assert_text("\$[\d]{0,1},{0,1}[\d]{2,3},{0,1}[\d]{0,3}")
  end
 end
```

... gives this error:

```
Then I should see 3 listings which contain the price in the correct format               # features/step_definitions/feature_format.rb:6
      Ambiguous match, found 3 elements matching css "div.psfm-hf-ft-price" (Capybara::Ambiguous)
```

Does anybody know what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

To use a regex you need to pass a regex not a string. So to check if the page matches your regex 3 times it would be

```
expect(page).to have_text(/\$[\d]{0,1},{0,1}[\d]{2,3},{0,1}[\d]{0,3}/, count: 3)
```

If `@page.price` refers to a piece of the page that contains all 3 prices then it would be

```
expect(@page.price).to have_text(/\$[\d]{0,1},{0,1}[\d]{2,3},{0,1}[\d]{0,3}/, count: 3)
```

However judging from the "ambiguous error" I'm guessing that your @page.price selector may actually be selecting an element that only has one price in it?  If thats the case you want something more like

```
expect(page).to have_css('div.psfm-hf-ft-price', text: /\$[\d]{0,1},{0,1}[\d]{2,3},{0,1}[\d]{0,3}/, count: 3)
```

which will check that the page has 3 elements matching the given css selector which each have content matching the regex

Comment: Thank you! Going to play with it some more, but I suspect have_css might be the right path to follow.